# Query filesystems and DB utilization using vi editor

Tags: unix, sybase, vi, isql

I am currently monitoring multiple systems' OS (Unix) filesystem utilization and DB (Sybase) utilization. I would like to query those in one file using the vi editor. My script goes like this:

df -h

su - sybpg1

isql -Usapsa -SPG1 -PMaster4SID -w999 -X

```
    declare @pagesize numeric(19,0)
    select @pagesize=(select @@maxpagesize)
    SELECT "Database Name" = CONVERT(char(30), db_name(D.dbid)),
    "Data Size MB" = STR(SUM(CASE WHEN U.segmap != 4 THEN U.size*@pagesize/1048576 END),10,1),
    "Used Data MB" = STR(SUM(CASE WHEN U.segmap != 4 THEN size - curunreservedpgs(U.dbid, U.lstart, U.unreservedpgs)END)*@pagesize/1048576,10,1),
    "Data Full%" = STR(100 * (1 - 1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN U.segmap != 4 THEN curunreservedpgs(U.dbid, U.lstart, U.unreservedpgs) END)/SUM(CASE WHEN U.segmap != 4 THEN U.size END)),9,1) ,
    "Log Size MB" = STR(SUM(CASE WHEN U.segmap = 4 THEN U.size*@pagesize/1048576 END),10,1),
    "Free Log MB" = STR(lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",D.dbid)*@pagesize/1048576,10,1),
    "Log Full%" = STR(100 * (1 - 1.0 * lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",D.dbid) /
    SUM(CASE WHEN U.segmap = 4 THEN U.size END)),8,1)
    FROM master..sysdatabases D,
    master..sysusages U
    WHERE U.dbid = D.dbid
    AND ((D.dbid != 2))
    GROUP BY D.dbid
    ORDER BY db_name(D.dbid)
    go
```

but whenever i execute: 
sh filename
It was able to enter sybase, however couldn't get pass through the isql line. 
It goes something like this:
sybsid.sh: line 6: isql: command not found

Hope you could help me out. 
Thanks!

Comment: can you check isql working on command prompt ?  your  environment variables may not be correct. Try to export the SYBASE and PATH environment variables in your shell script.

Comment: SYBASE.sh set the Sybase environment variables. you can source SYBASE.sh in your script. SYBASE.sh should be in $SYBASE .

Comment: Should i include 
$SYBASE/SYBASE.sh on my script after su -sybpg1 line?

Comment: you should try and test, including after su -sybpg1 line or in the beginning of the file.